# How can I fix bitbucket pipelines from crashing when running out of memory?

Tags: docker, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to run the following pipeline in bitbucket pipelines for a salesforce SFRA project. It is working great until I add a couple more sites to our build setup. I have already added in the 2x and the docker memory of 7128. Are there any other ways to optimize this pipeline so it stops crashing? I also am not positive that the caches step is setup correctly. I had to hide most of the logs for security and privacy.

Here is the error I am getting in the log. This error shows up on the `npm run compile:js:prod` step every time.

```
Killed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
```

And here is my pipeline

```
image: node:10.18.0

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 7128
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Test Code
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run lint
            - npm test
  custom:
    deployment-to-staging:
      - step:
          name: Test Code
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run lint
            - npm test
      - step:
          name: Deploy To Staging
          deployment: staging
          size: 2x
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run compile:svg
            - npm run compile:scss:prod
            - npm run compile:js:prod
            - npm run compile:fonts:prod
            - npm run deployCartridges <options hidden>
```

Comment: You can add docker into the cache section as well. But when you say added more sites... Do you mean build and deploy from a single pipeline to multiple sites?

Comment: @EugeneDW Thanks for the response. How would I add docker in here? I just would not want to get that wrong. I assume just put `- docker` in the caches section?

When I say added sites, I mean that the compile steps are compiling js/scss/fonts for as many folders as we have sites. We have 25 now. We probably had 20 before or so. So when we add a few more sites this error starts happening.

Comment: @EugeneDW On a side note, I can build this all just fine in Jenkins. I assume because it does not have a limit on memory.

Comment: Correct just add - docker under cache section. I would recommend splitting out the builds in seperate pipelines. If all the sites are using the same css js etc might be worth pushing those as npm packages as sperate pipelines and then referecing those dependencies in your projects which will form part of their own build process. That way you can cache the npm packages within those build steps as - node. Jenkins most likely yes has a higher limit if you ask me :)

Comment: @Metropolis would you consider posting your solution as an answer if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add next section too.

```
options:
  docker: true
  size: 2x
```

As it's describe in [bitbucket pipeline error - container 'docker' exceeded memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784443/9066900)

So the way it's working on my side see on next screenshot:

[image: options: docker: true size: 2x]